# Getting id null while calling a request in reactjs v6 or this.props.match.params.id not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

```
class TodosComponent extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state= {
     id: this.props.id,//here id is not getting properly set i think
     description: 'My name is prathvi',
     targetDate : moment(new Date()).format('YYYT-MM-DD')    
    }
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    this.validate = this.validate.bind(this)
   }
   componentDidMount(){
   let username = AuthenticationService.getUserLoggedIn();
    TodoDataService.retriveTodo(username,this.state.id)//while calling   
  request i am getting error bcoz id is going as undefined
   .then(response=> this.setState({
    description : response.data.description,
    targetDate : moment(response.data.targetDate).format('YYYT-MM-DD') 
    }))
     }
```

//code for calling spring boot service

```
 import axios from "axios";
 class TodoDataService{
retriveAllTodos(name){
return axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/users/${name}/todos`)
}

retriveTodo(name,id){
return axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/users/${name}/todos/${id}`)
}

deleteTodos(name,id){
return axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/users/${name}/todos/${id}`)
}


}
 export default new TodoDataService();
```

Questn: In above class TodoComponent inside this.state i have declared id, which is returning null when I am calling a request getting this error : GET http://localhost:8080/users/prathvi/todos/**undefined** 400. Actually I am a beginer and I am watching tutorial and making the program. He is using react 5 and am having react 6. Actually he is using id: this.props.match.params.id inside this.state. And if I am using it i am getting this error TodosComponent.jsx:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params').  Can anyone help me what to use to solve this error. I have gone through multiple post but not getting this error solved.

Comment: You can try console.log(this.props) in `constructor(props){}` to see when constructor invoke does this.props have id value. And console.log in `componentDidMount(){}` too to see value of this.props when component mount. If in componentDidMount this.props has id value then just change to `TodoDataService.retriveTodo(username,this.props.id)`

Comment: inside constructor: undefined

TodosComponent.jsx:17 inside constructor: undefined

TodosComponent.jsx:22 inside component did mount[object Object]

Constructor  is printing undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is why id is returning undefined is : I have not injected params to my class. And I am trying changes to same class TodosComponent class by making id: this.props.match.params.id, or trying different thing at componentDidMount function. You can see the question, how I was using it.

Below is my working code: For V6
STEP1: initialise id like below

```
class TodosComponent extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state= {
     id: this.props.params.id,//initialisg id in react v6
     description: 'My name is prathvi',
     targetDate : moment(new Date()).format('YYYT-MM-DD')
        
    }
     console.log(this.props.params.id) 
    }
    //remaing code of class which is not useful.
```

STEP2: Create a file with withParams.jsx or other name with .jsx extension and paste below code.

```
 import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

  function withParams(Component) {
 return props => <Component {...props} params={useParams()} />;
 }

 export default withParams
```

STEP3:  inject useParams to a place where you have declare Routing info

```
import withParams from './withParams'
class TodoApp extends Component {
 render() {
   
    const TodosComponentWithParams = withParams(TodosComponent);//this is how we 
    are injecting the class which we declare in step1
   
    return (

        <div className='TodoApp'>
            
            <Router >
            
                <Routes>

                    <Route path='/todos/:id' element={<AuthenticateRoute> 
                //using here    <TodosComponentWithParams/></AuthenticateRoute>} 
         />
                    
                </Routes>
            </Router>
           
        </div>
         );
         }}
      export default TodoApp;
```

Now after doing this if you run the code the console.log statement of  class TodosComponent instead of printing undefind , it will print the value.